# directed acyclic graph in sigma.js

Tags: javascript, directed-acyclic-graphs, gephi, sigma.js

while it is possible to make directed graphs in sigma.js, does it support graphing hierarchical graphs? I know that it can read GEXF files, so I tried creating my graph in gephi. The graph itself can be created but not laid out correctly. There is a plug-in in gephi to create layouts for directed acyclic graphs, but my graph is too big for it to complete the layout. Are there any other way to get a large directed acyclic graph into sigma.js?

Comment: How large is your graph?

Comment: @YannisP. ~400,000 vertices